# NullPointerException while using POSTaggerMe of OpenNLP in Android

Tags: java, android, opennlp

I am trying to use Apache OpenNLP in an Android application. I'm encountering a `NullPointerException`. The steps I'm doing are as follows

1. Train a custom model.

   ```
    private POSModel getCustomPosModel() {

           POSModel model = null;
           InputStream dataIn = null;
           ObjectStream<String> lineStream;
           ObjectStream<POSSample> sampleStream = null;

           try {
               dataIn =aManager.open("customPOS.train");
               lineStream = new PlainTextByLineStream(dataIn, "UTF-8");
               sampleStream = new WordTagSampleStream(lineStream);
               model = POSTaggerME.train("en", sampleStream, opennlp.tools.util.model.ModelType.MAXENT, null, null, 5, 5);
           } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           } 
             return model;
       }
   ```
2. Use the custom model obtained by the above method to tag a set of tokens as shown below

   ```
       public String[] tagTokensForInfo(String[] tokens){

       POSModel model =null;
       String[] posTags = null;
       model = getCustomPosModel();
       POSTaggerME posTagger = null;

       posTagger = new POSTaggerME(model);
       posTags = posTagger.tag(tokens);
       System.out.println("The tags and tokens are shown below");
       for(int i=0;i<posTags.length;i++){
           System.out.println("Token : "+tokens[i]+" ,Tags : "+posTags[i]);
       }
       return posTags;
   }
   ```

When I run the emulator and the above method is called , i am getting a null pointer exception with the following reason

```
04-01 06:13:23.935: I/dalvikvm(906): Failed resolving Lopennlp/tools/util/ext/OSGiExtensionLoader; interface 1515 'Lorg/osgi/framework/BundleActivator;'


04-01 06:13:23.935: W/dalvikvm(906): Link of class 'Lopennlp/tools/util/ext/OSGiExtensionLoader;' failed
04-01 06:13:23.945: I/dalvikvm(906): Could not find method opennlp.tools.util.ext.OSGiExtensionLoader.getInstance, referenced from method 


opennlp.tools.util.ext.ExtensionLoader.instantiateExtension
04-01 06:13:23.945: W/dalvikvm(906): VFY: unable to resolve static method 8352: Lopennlp/tools/util/ext/OSGiExtensionLoader;.getInstance ()Lopennlp/tools/util/ext/OSGiExtensionLoader;
```

ANd the complete stack trace is shown below

```
04-01 06:13:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(906): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 06:13:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(906): Process: net.viralpatel.android.speechtotextdemo, PID: 906
04-01 06:13:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(906): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 06:13:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at opennlp.tools.util.BeamSearch.bestSequences(BeamSearch.java:118)
04-01 06:13:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at opennlp.tools.util.BeamSearch.bestSequence(BeamSearch.java:198)
04-01 06:13:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at opennlp.tools.postag.POSTaggerME.tag(POSTaggerME.java:227)
04-01 06:13:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at opennlp.tools.postag.POSTaggerME.tag(POSTaggerME.java:223)
04-01 06:13:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at com.intuit.opennlp.CustomerTagger.tagTokensForInvoiceInfo(CustomerTagger.java:32)
04-01 06:13:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at com.intuit.opennlp.ExtractInvoiceInfo.extract(ExtractInvoiceInfo.java:28)
04-01 06:13:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at net.viralpatel.android.speechtotextdemo.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)
04-01 06:13:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
04-01 06:13:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
04-01 06:13:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-01 06:13:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-01 06:13:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-01 06:13:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
04-01 06:13:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 06:13:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-01 06:13:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
04-01 06:13:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
04-01 06:13:24.015: E/AndroidRuntime(906):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Has anyone run into this error, or can you please help me sole this???

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check line number 46 of your MainActivity.java class.

Comment: hi sid, its the entry point of the program, it calls the extract() method which in turn calls the tagTokensForInfo()  method i have mentioned before, could you please elaborate a little upon your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: @yash From the stack trace I see that the `extract()` method calls `tagTokensForInvoiceInfo()`, not the one you defined ad `tagTokensForInfo()`. For what I know there is no mention of the methods you posted in the stack trace, are you sure about the program flow?

Comment: @5agado, its true , both the methods are same, while typing here , i made a mistake , its actually tagTokensForInvoiceInfo() method itself. no ambiguity there.

Comment: @yash Well, then according to the official documentation you should do something like `model = POSTaggerME.train("en", sampleStream, TrainingParameters.defaultParams(), null, null)`. In your case the problem is exactly about the model (it remains null). Also I think you are using the deprecated version of the method.

Comment: @5agado hey , i tried using the solution that you provided, but its still the same, im still getting same NullPointerException like in the question i posted.Any training method i use, i get the deprecated warning, the autosuggestion in eclipse gives three methods to train, i tried using all of them , and i get deprecated for all the three methods. please let me know if i am missing anything.

Comment: @yash As I said I think that simple the model is null, so you should check the validity of all the variables that you're using in order to train it. Also check the OpenNLP version, if it is possible try to use the newest one.